# Build EGit repository outside Eclipse workspace

Tags: egit

I use *Eclipse 3.7* and *EGit 1.0*. If I create repositories inside my Eclipse workspace (as a sub-folder for a project) everything works fine. But obviously this is not recommended so I want to build a repository in a place elsewhere. But this does not work as expected.

I make this steps:

1. Create a simple Eclipse project with a text file in it (**myproject**).
2. *Share -> Team -> Git*
3. Create Button -> use **c:\user** as *Parent Directory* and **mygit** as *Name*
4. I leave *Path within Repository* empty
5. so *Target Location* is **c:/user/mygit/myproject** -> Finish

At this point I expect that I can manage my code via *EGit*. But if I choose the *Team* menu within the project or text file context menu I see **no** version control options like *commit* etc.
On the other hand if I delete the created repository the project is also deleted.

Does anybody know how to do this correctly? At first my goal is to build a simple single user repository.

Comment: Do you know why it's not recommended to create a repository in your workspace? It's the only thing that seems to work for me.

Comment: I don't know why this is not recommended. I think this can lead to trouble if you're sharing repository among team members.

Comment: Ah, this seems to explain why: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/User_Guide#Considerations_for_Git_Repositories_to_be_used_in_Eclipse -- It doesn't seem dangerous if your goal is to get it all up on Github in the first place and/or go with a one project one repository rule.

Answer (score 7):

It's quite simple (my setup: Eclipse 3.7, EGIT 1.1.0). The standard layout is to put your project inside (below) a GIT repository, so that you can have more than one Eclipse project in one repository - outside the Eclipse workspace tree.

Then, we first **create the repository**: In the "Git repositories" view, we create a new (non-bare) repository:
For example, in the dialog we fill:

```
Create a new repository
```

- Parent directory: `c:\user\gitreps\`    (a directory you use to store git repositories)
- Name : **repo1**                          (your repository name)

This will create  `c:\user\gitreps\repo1\.git\`

After this we share the existing project, which will trigger a physical move:

Take your new project, (no matter where was it created, inside or outside the workspace dir) and share it:

> Project (**myproj**) -> RightClick -> Team -> Share -> Git

In the dialog list select the repositoy you just created (repo1) and leave the rest blank.
See that the *"Current location"* and *"Target location"* 
In our example, the "Target location" should be `c:\user\gitreps\repo1\myproj`

When you press *Finish*, the project will be physically moved as we want.

Comment: After the last step (_Finish_) the project was actually moved to c:\user\gitreps\repo1\.git\ but **myproj** is still not _gitable_. There is no branch name displayed right after the project name and in _Team_ -> _Share_ there are no GIT options.

Comment: Works perfectly for me. Of course, myproj should end in  c:\user\gitreps\repo1\myproj  (not in c:\user\gitreps\repo1\.git )

Comment: Yes - of course it ends in **c:\user\gitreps\repo1\myproj**. Don't know what's wrong after that step. Thanks anyway!